# Remove dict structure from list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures, type-conversion

Say I have a list of dicts looking like this:

self = [ {x: '1'}, {x: '7'}, {x: '8'}, {x: '9'}, {x: '1'}, {x: '4'}, {x: '7'}, {x: '7'}, {x: '7'}, {x: '7'} ]

And I want to remove all dict structures and only keeping their elements, to end up with a list looking like this:

[1,7,8,9,1,4,7,7,7,7]

Is there any function in python supporting that?

Comment: `[int(i['x']) for i in self_dict]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
lst = [ {'x': '1'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '8'}, {'x': '9'}, {'x': '1'}, {'x': '4'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'} ]
print([int(a.get('x')) for a in lst])
```

This will result in :

```
[1, 7, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```

**Note** that the **dictionaries** inside the list have keys as **`'x'`** instead of **`x`** as declared in the question.

Comment: Thank you! that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the map function

```
a = [{'x': '1'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '8'}, {'x': '9'}, {'x': '1'}, {'x': '4'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'}, {'x': '7'}]

b = list(map(lambda e: e['x'], a))

print (b)
```

Result:

```
['1', '7', '8', '9', '1', '4', '7', '7', '7', '7']
```

Comment: Thank you! that was helpful